# IDE with C++Builder xe 2 & Scintilla

Tags: ide, c++builder, scintilla, c++builder-xe2

I just starting a new project, what it is ? I want to develop a new IDE and we investigate ( ) and found Scintilla ( is very usefull all the features this library offer ). So I decide to start looking how to use Scintilla with C++Builder XE 2 ... i found that exists ScintillaNET, wxScintilla but i don´t now how to use this in a MDI project in C++Builder IDE...

If somebody have an idea or known how or where i could start I really apprecciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [C++Builder Developers Journal](http://bcbjournal.org/) has a [Wrapping the Scintilla Control](http://bcbjournal.org/?loc=all_issues&vol=15) series of articles, which began in the December 2011 issue.

To read to the articles requires a [subscription](http://bcbjournal.org/?loc=subscriptions), which are inexpensive and provide full access to all previous issues.